# Custom frontmatter variables with Markdown Remark in Gatsby.js

Tags: markdown, graphql, gatsby, yaml-front-matter, remarkjs

I am building a website using Gatsbyjs and NetlifyCMS. I've started using this starter https://github.com/AustinGreen/gatsby-starter-netlify-cms, and I am trying to customise it now.

I want to use custom variables in the frontmatter of a markdown file like this:

```
---
templateKey: mirror
nazev: Černobílá
title: Black and White
cena: '2700'
price: '108'
thumbnail: /img/img_1659.jpeg
---
```

I want to acess this data with GraphQL. I use gatsby-source-filesystem and gatsby-transform-remark. This is my query:

```
  {
  allMarkdownRemark {
    edges {
      node {
        frontmatter {
          templateKey
          nazev
          title
          cena
          price
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can't get the GraphQL to read my own variables, it recognises only `title` and `templateKey` (those, that were already used in the starter). I get this error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"nazev\" on type \"frontmatter_2\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 7,
          "column": 11
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"cena\" on type \"frontmatter_2\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 9,
          "column": 11
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"price\" on type \"frontmatter_2\". Did you mean \"pricing\"?",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 10,
          "column": 11
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've searched for days, but found nothing. Would someone help me please?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was that the newly-added properties in the frontmatter of my markdown file didn't show up in my GraphQL.

All I had to do was to restart the server with 'gatsby-develop'.

Comment: Can you explain more? I can't figure this out!

Comment: Just restart Gatsby to let the 'gatsby-transformer-remark' know that you have done changes to the frontmatter :)

Comment: I'm truly impressed you didn't need to restart gatsby for days. I literally restart it every 5 minutes because of errors

Comment: If you using GraphiQL might need to reload browser too.

Comment: @RobertWolf thanks a lot, I also had the same question and I wasn't finding nothing in the documentation, but restart the service and reload the page of GraphiQL is all the needed. Thanks!

Comment: Also found that the directory with the markdown files has to be read by `gatsby-source-filesystem`, otherwise  `gatsby-transformer-remark` will not work with that information


    {
          resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
          options: {
            path: `${__dirname}/content/mycollection`,
            name: `mycollection`,
          },
        },

Comment: Don't you also have to add this data to the definitions in gatsby-node `exports.createPages` ? for an initial page list setup?

Answer (score 2):

#### Some background information that might help you anticipate similar issues in the future

`gatsby-transformer-remark` and all other plugins that are dependant on GraphQL queries can only read newly added variables when the GraphQL queries are run.

In Gatsby, GraphQL queries are run **ONCE at startup of your development server**. 
The queries will not be refreshed if you alter the code while `gatsby develop` is still live. You can run your GraphQL queries again by restarting with `gatsby develop`.

The Gatsby documentation has its own entry of the [Gatsby Build Process](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/) that shows when exactly the queries are run:

```
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.051 s
// ...
success onPostBootstrap - 0.130 s
⠀
info bootstrap finished - 3.674 s
⠀
success run static queries - 0.057 s — 3/3 89.08 queries/second  // GraphQL queries here
success run page queries - 0.033 s — 5/5 347.81 queries/second   // GraphQL queries here
success start webpack server - 1.707 s — 1/1 6.06 pages/second
```

As a rule of thumb that I learned from experience, if you are wondering why your code changes are not hot reloading

- refresh the browser.
- If that doesn't work, restart `gatsby develop`.
- If that doesn't work, run `gatsby clean`, clear your browser's site cache, and run `gatsby develop`.
- If that doesn't work you can be *almost* 100% certain you made a mistake.