# How to get custom remarks in markdown with gatsby-transformer-remark?

Tags: markdown, gatsby, remarkjs

My markdown has some extra remarks and looks like this:

```
---
path: "/"
date: "2018-10-12"
title: "xxxx"
description: "desccc"
---

some of the text
```

How can I get the description?

```
{
  allMarkdownRemark(
    sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
    limit: 1000
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        frontmatter {
          path
          title
          date
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that head part of the markdown document is most commonly referred as `frontmatter` and is automatically transformed for you so just add the `description` field to your graphql query inside the `frontmatter { ... }` structure and use it as your would use the `title` field for example.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've already tried but I don't have the field there. Are you sure it works out of the box or I need to do something else? Cheers

Comment: Yes, as long as you're using the `gatsby-transformer-remark` and I believe you are.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. I add custom fields and they are undefined. If I remove the "date" I get the "date" as null, therefore I think there is something that knows about what fields is expecting. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Just read another post ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48329511/custom-frontmatter-variables-with-markdown-remark-in-gatsby-js ) and I need to restart the gatsby server.

Comment: Lol, I remember leaving a comment on that one

Comment: Yes you did, I forgot to mention haha